# php post remote wildcard filename

Tags: php, wildcard, fopen, file-exists

I need my php script to look on a remote http server (I'm assuming via fopen) and it needs to find this unique filename if it exists.  If it does exist, I need it to display.  But this remote filename will be changing over time and it needs to be limited to the first one it finds in case there are multiple remote files on accident.

ie the filename could be this:
`domain.com/filename-1.zip`
or this
`domain.com/filename-2.zip`

How would I post this dynamic, remote filename in my local script and limit it to just 1?
ie `domain.com/filename-*.zip`

Comment: You cannot guess a URL based on a wildcard, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The remote server would have to cooperate and tell you what filenames are available. That means a script which explicitly tells you (or serves up) a file matching some parameters, or allows directory browsing allowing you to parse out filenames and find whatever you want.